# asp.net RadioButton is display false always for selenium

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a UI as follows and im trying to automate this.

[image]

my html content is as follows:

```html
<div class="medium-5 columns tableheading-td">
  <ul id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers" class="assessment-main-layout tabled-list" onchange="ChangeTextColorForSelectedRadio(this);">
    <li>
      <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$QuetionListPlaceHolder$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754$rdbListAnswers"
        value="0">
      <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_0"> </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$QuetionListPlaceHolder$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754$rdbListAnswers"
        value="1">
      <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_1"> </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_2" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$QuetionListPlaceHolder$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754$rdbListAnswers"
        value="2" style="">
      <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_2"> </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_3" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$QuetionListPlaceHolder$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754$rdbListAnswers"
        value="3">
      <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_3"> </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_4" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$QuetionListPlaceHolder$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1$BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754$rdbListAnswers"
        value="4">
      <label for="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_4"> </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

im trying to click my radio buttons as follows:

```
IWebElement webElement= CommonProperties.driver.FindElement(By.Id("ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_2"));
webElement.ClickElement();
```

but it says element is display false.
What is he reason for this and how can i fix this?
[image]

i have tried with xpath:

```
 IWebElement webElement= CommonProperties.driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_0']"));
```

(having two xpath for radio button and label. even though getting same issue.

```
//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_0"]

//*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers"]/li[1]/label
```

> OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException   HResult=0x80131500
>   Message=element not visible   (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315
>   (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT
>   10.0.10586 x86_64)   Source=WebDriver
>
> StackTrace:    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response
>   errorResponse)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver.Execute(String
>   driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Execute(String
>   commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)    at
>   OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebElement.Click()    at
>   SeleniumBL.SeleniumSetMethods.ClickElement(IWebElement element) in
>   D:\SourceControl\Test\Test
>   \SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\SeleniumBL\SeleniumSetMethods.cs:line
>   53    at
>   SeleniumHR.Models.Assesment.BigFiftyAssesment.AssesmentPlay() in
>   D:\SourceControl\Test\Test
>   \SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\Models\Assesment\BigFiftyAssesment.cs:line
>   47    at SeleniumHR.Models.AssesmentBase.AssesmentStart() in
>   D:\SourceControl\Test\Test
>   \SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\Models\Assesment\AssesmentBase.cs:line
>   216    at
>   SeleniumHR.Models.Assesment.BigFiftyAssesment.ExecuteAssesment() in
>   D:\SourceControl\Test\Test
>   \SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\SeleniumHRM\Models\Assesment\BigFiftyAssesment.cs:line
>   24    at
>   SeleniumHR.Models.Assesment.AssesmentFactory.AssesmentPlay(String
>   AssesmentType) in D:\SourceControl\Test\Test
>   \SeleniumHRM\SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\Models\Assesment\AssesmentFactory.cs:line
>   48    at SeleniumHRM.Program.Main(String[] args) in
>   D:\SourceControl\Test\Test
>   \SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\SeleniumHR\Program.cs:line 49

Nuget i have used as follows:
[image]

Comment: Sorry Unable to reproduce your problem. It is working here.

Comment: Can you post your error trace?

Comment: what you could do give wait for the element or check if it is inside any `frame`?

Comment: @KajalKundu i have put thread.wait but still same issue

Comment: Just check if it is inside any iframe?

Comment: @KajalKundu - no iframe. i have edited for exception details

Comment: Sometimes with sites there are two (or more) versions, e.g. desktop and mobile. Are you sure that the first element found is actually visible? Go into Chrome, open the dev tools, and type `$$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_2")`. Does it return 1 or more than 1? That's a CSS selector for an ID (`#`).

Comment: @JeffC only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out my problem. According to style classes radio button is disabled. therefore its always display false. I was able to click on radio button using click on the related label text. I did it as follows

```
 // get lable for selected radio button
IWebElement radioButtonSelectedLabel = CommonProperties.driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("label[for='ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_0']"));
// click on the label
radioButtonSelectedLabel.ClickElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exception details : element not visible (Session info: chrome=72.0.3626.109) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.10586 x86_64)
```

This shows that you are using older version of `chromedriver=2.37.544315` which is not compatible with `chrome version 72`. You need to upgrade your chrome driver to become compatible.I believe this will resolve your problem.

Please see the following [link](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Comment: it does not solve my problem. still giving me same error.for packages i have installed, please check the question

Comment: Are you using selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to use **visibilityOfElementLocated** this to wait element before click

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
var clickableElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//*[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_QuetionListPlaceHolder_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestion1_BigFiftyPersonalityQuestionItem1221754_rdbListAnswers_0']")));
```